# UNIX transition state diagram

Tags: unix, operating-system, kernel

Why is the running state of Unix (in the state transition diagram) split into "User Running" and "Kernel Running".. and how can i map my answer to a type of Operating System implementation

Comment: This is no longer true since the invention of multiprocessing. In a multiprocessor system, one CPU core can be running kernel code and the other CPU core can be running user code. So this is a bit out of date...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User running is typically where pure computation happens - ex: math, manipulation of data structures, parsing of user input, etc. Kernel mode is what happens when you make a syscall - ex: `read()` `write()` `open()` `ioctl()` or really anything interacting with devices, files, or kernel services. If you want to know why, consider the guarantees on stability you could make if arbitrary processes could manipulate bytes on disk directly rather than through abstractions like a filesystem.